# Share the custom framework without sharing the code

Tags: ios, swift

How we can share the custom framework without sharing the code?
I was using via carthage but we can see the whole source code. Other thing I tried was only shared .framework but while debugging again I can see the source code. Is there any way we can share without source code?

Comment: You can use cocoapods to share your packed framework or static library with header files, not sure about carthage

Comment: I even tried with cocoapods we can see the source code. Didn't try static libray till now. Will it work for swift(static library) ?

Comment: you have to pack your source code into `.framework` file and share that file through cocoapods, cocoapods doesnt do it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try static framework.

1. Add a new target of static framework
2. Move all relevant files to framework folder and upadate its targets.
3. In main target add target dependency and link with lib. to that frameworks.

Ref : https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios